# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [69, 4]

Tags: keras, red, deepl

Estoy haciendo una red neuronal para predecir parámetros como la velocidad máxima, latencia, amplitud y AUC de una curva de crecimiento de levaduras. Para ello, mi idea planteada es usar los primeros valores de la serie como entradas y las salidas que sean estos parámetros. He intentado el siguiente código pero me sale ese error. transposed_data es el dataframe que se compone de la primera columna el tiempo y el resto de columnas son los datos de crecimiento para cada muestra. En este ejemplo estoy probando primero con una sola.

```
curva = np.array(transposed_data['Sample X26'])


scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
values = curva.reshape(-1, 1)
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)

X = scaled
y = np.array([latencia, velocidad_maxima, amplitud, auc])


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(69, activation='relu', input_shape=(4,)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(69, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(4)  # 4 salidas correspondientes a velocidad máxima, latencia, amplitud        y AUC
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')


model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)


predictions = model.predict(X_test)


auc = roc_auc_score(y_test[3], predictions[:, 3])


r2_ajustado = r2_score(y_test, predictions)


print("Latencia (predicción):", predictions[:, 0])
print("Velocidad Máxima (predicción):", predictions[:, 1])
print("Amplitud (predicción):", predictions[:, 2])
print("AUC:", auc)
```